# convert const reference to smart pointer without copying

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr

I have a class Object which is very expensive to copy. I wrote a function which takes a const reference to Object as a function argument. Now in the function I need to call a function which takes a shared pointer to Object.  How can I call this function without copying the whole object at least one time?

Comment: [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) has a constructor that accepts a custom deleter. I'm sure you now realize how you can pass the address of your object safely.

Comment: Why does the function take a shared pointer? Does it store it somewhere as a side-effect?

Comment: the function is a constructor of another class and I assume the pointer gets stored as a member variable.

Comment: There is a reason for things, unless the engineer (the programmer for computer programs) is silly. That reason might mean you need to allocate the object dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the aliasing constructor of the shared pointer:

```
void f(std::shared_ptr<X>);  // the other function

void my_function(const X& x)
{
    f(std::shared_ptr<X>(nullptr, &x));
}
```

Note however that it's not clear that this will be correct: It is vital in this situation that nothing below `f` takes ownership shares that extend past the actual lifetime of `x` in your function. If `f` is designed correctly, then it stands to reason that it expects a shared pointer so that it *can* arbitrarily take out additional lifetime shares, so I would only use this with extreme caution.

The only "correct" solution (other than changing the signature of your function) is to actually manage the lifetime of the object in question with a shared pointer, and the perhaps add an `enable_shared_from_this` facility to `X`:

```
void my_function(const X& x)
{
    f(x.shared_from_this());  // X must be changed to support this
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Take the address of the reference, do a const_cast to get rid of the const then pass a null deleter along with the pointer to the smart pointer constructor. A null deleter is a deleter that performs no action. i.e.

```
std::shared_ptr(const_cast<my_type*>(&myRef), [] (my_type *) { })
```

Note that if the function you are passing to actually expects to perform lifetime management on the parameter you may well end up needing to copy the object.

Comment: A null deleter is almost always the sign of a design issue (yes, I know there are valid uses)